# How can i pass Actions info to Component, React + Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i'm doing a API request on my Action.js and when it's done, send a 'success' parameter to the component which it's calling the action.

What it's the best way to do that?

My code:

Action.js

```
export const setarLojas = (lojas) =>{
    return {
      type: SETAR_LOJAS,
      data: lojas
    }
  }

  export const carregarLojas = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      return API.get('loja')
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setarLojas(response.data))

        // Example
        // return "success"
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      })
    }
  }
```

Component.js

```
componentDidMount(){
      this.props.carregarLojas();

      // Example
      // if(this.props.carregarLojas == "success") { alert("success") }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a status (as state in your reducer, in addition to your data) related to your action;

```
setarLojas: {
      data: actionData, 
      status: actionStatus
}
```

Then change the value of your status according to your action's result,

example values to use for the status state : `'request' | 'error' | 'timeout' | 'success'.`

example action:

```
export const setarLojas = (lojas, status) =>{
   return {
      type: SETAR_LOJAS,
      data: lojas,
      status: status
   }
 }

export const carregarLojas = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(setarLojas({}, 'request'));
      return API.get('loja')
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setarLojas(response.data, 'success'));
      })
      .catch(error => {
         dispatch(setarLojas({}, 'error'));
         throw(error);
      })
    }
  }
```

In your components, after connecting it to the redux using the connect hoc, you can get your data like:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
     setarLojasData: state.YOUR_REDUCER.getIn(['setarLojasData', 'data']), 
     setarLojasStatus: state.YOUR_REDUCER.getIn(['setarLojasData', 'status'])
})
```

There you go, you have now the status that describe your action's result and according to its value, you can manage your view then use the data.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion!!!!
I made a status: { type: 'action.type', result: 'action.result' } in my reducer, now i can controll all the actions

Comment: You're welcome! Like i explained before, to have more controll you can add a string param ({ type: 'action.type', result: 'action.result', resultStatus: 'action.resultStatus'} for example) to your status that will describe more the flux of your action **request => error OR success OR timeout** then you can know simply that your action passes from 'request' to 'success' (action succeed), from 'request' to 'error' (action failed with error) or from 'request' to 'timeout (action failed with tiemout). And Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Redux middleware [Thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) to solve async api call issue. Thunk will handle your async api call.

Comment: i'm already using it, but i didn't understand how to pass action info to component

Comment: You have to call function into dispatch like dispatch(()=>carregarLojas). For more reference see my this github repository https://github.com/Sangammm/News-React_Redux_Middleware